# Change Backcolor of Excel Cells in Range with Highest Value

Tags: excel, vba

So this code gets the highest value of a cell in a range. But what I'm trying to do is change the back color of the cells to yellow with the highest value. Any suggestions?

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMax As Double



'Set range from which to determine largest value
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100")


'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range 

dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

'Displays largest value
MsgBox dblMax
```

Comment: Why don't just use conditional formatting? No VBA needed at all. What if 2 cells have the max value? If it really has to be VBA checkout the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to get the row number of the `dblMax` value.

Answer (score 1):

#### Conditional formatting

You can do that just using conditional formatting without any VBA. Just format the upper 1 Value. If 2 values have the same max both are formatted.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Conditional formatting: Format only upper or lower values (upper 1) • Sorry for the german screenshot.</sup>*

#### VBA soultion

You can use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to get the row number of the `dblMax` value:

```
'Set range from which to determine largest value
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A100")

'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range
Dim dblMax As Double
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

'Find row number of max value
Dim MaxRow As Double
MaxRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dblMax, rng, 0)

'make it yellow
rng.Cells(MaxRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Note that VBA will only find the find and color the first max value if 2 exist.